# put some comment on image and hover it

Tags: android, image, hover, touch

I need to apply some text on the part of the image where a touch event is occurred. Its just like the Image Tagging on facebook. Please provide some clue how to go about it.

What I've done so far is that I am loading image from gallery and showing it on image viewer.

```
public class LoadImg extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
float x,y;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    x=0;y=0;
    Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent i = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                     android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }
    });
```

Implementing the OnTouchListener, I m locating the x and y coordinates .

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    x=event.getX();
    y=event.getY();

    return false;

}
```

But imageviewer doesnt has any method to add text on the coordinates.
I dont want to preset a text/toast. I want to get a edittext/toast to get generated when a user touches the image.

Comment: first your homework pls

Comment: @PareshMayani I have added my home work sir !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the `x`, `y` positions using `event.getX()`, `event.getY()`.
Then, at those positions add a textview to the layout. Like:

```
TextView tv=new TextView(this);
```

add layout params and left margin and top margin with those `x`, `y` values

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams trparams = new 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
trparams.leftmargin=x;
trparams.topmargin=y;
tv.setLayoutParams(trparams);
```

then add this textview to the layout.

Comment: I hv edited the code still not working. M not able to add the left margin and top margin.            `ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
             if(x!=0 && y!=0)
             {
              TextView tv=new TextView(this);
              LinearLayout.LayoutParams trparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                 tv.setLayoutParams(trparams);
                          
             }`

Comment: you can add trparams.leftmargin=x;trparams.topmargin=y; then set the layoutparams to textview.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it, you can use a longClickListener and show a toast message with your tip string in it..

```
Toast viewToast = Toast.makeText(this, "Your tool tip", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
yourView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLongClick(View v) {
        viewToast.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: By this way there would be same toast everytime user touches the screen. I want diff text everytime user touches it